# Reading documents from file when using sklearn.feature_extraction.text CountVectorizer

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am able to use code as in the example from the documentation, where the input to the fit_transform() function is a list of sentences, i.e:

```
corpus = [
   'this is the first document',
   'this is the second second document',
   'and the third one',
   'is this the first document?'
]
```

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

and get expected data out.  But when I try to replace corpus with a list of files, or file objects as the documentation suggests it can be:

"
 fit(raw_documents, y=None)

```
Learn a vocabulary dictionary of all tokens in the raw documents.
Parameters :    
raw_documents : iterable
    An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.
Returns :   
self :
```

"

.. so there is something missing in my understanding of the pipeline, I think.  Given a directory of files that I would like to CountVectorize, how do I do that?
if I try to feed a list of file objects, as [open(file,'r')] the error message I get is that file objects have no lower function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the vectorizer's `input` [constructor parameter](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn-feature-extraction-text-tfidfvectorizer) to either `filename` or `file`. Its default value is `content`, which assumes you've already read the files into memory.

Comment: Thanks, this was where I got lost in interpreting the documentation. I actually input the files directly to the constructor, but got no warnings from that so I didn't see it.