# python 2.7 - CountVectorizer error :AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

```
f1 = open("C:\\Users\\Keshav\\Desktop\\iHeal\\data1\\black_and_white\\1_1.dat","r")
f2 = open("C:\\Users\\Keshav\\Desktop\\iHeal\\data1\\black_and_white\\1_2.dat","r")
list1=[]
list1.append(f1)
list1.append(f2)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer(list1)
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(list1)
print X_train_counts
```

I'm trying to read a set of files and implement the CountVectorizer on them.

So list1 contains a list of file objects appended in it.

The resulting output is :

```
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I had a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592892/reading-documents-from-file-when-using-sklearn-feature-extraction-text-countvect/) - I passed list1 as parameter to the constructor also. The error persists.

How to correctly pass the list of file objects to the CountVectorizer method and get the matrix?

Comment: You want to do: count_vect = CountVectorizer(input='file')

Comment: @MarkR., if that's the answer, please post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), in your case the Vectorizer should be initialized with the input parameter set to 'file'. Therefore:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(input="file")
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(list1)
```

Comment: Hi how about the input is a list? Got 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'